# highcharts : issue in plotting 2 graphs in 1 chart

Tags: highcharts

I have 2 graphs in 1 chart. The range of x-axis values for 1st graph is from 1 to 100. The range of x-axis values for 2nd graph is from 1 to 30. So, when the graphs are plotted in the chart, the 2nd graph gets plotted in very small area. So, it becomes difficult to read 2nd graph. My requirement - both the charts to be readable. Can anyone help me in doing this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up two axes - one for each series.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4v0a07op/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: [{
        },{
            opposite: true
        }],
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        series: [{
            name: '1 to 30',
            xAxis: 1,
            data: [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,10]
        }, {
            name: '1 to 100',
            xAxis: 0,
            data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
        }]
    });
});
```